# Shopify - Update/Delete metafield via metafield API using PHP

Tags: php, curl, shopify

I've been stuck trying to update or delete a metafield that i created on user registration via the shopify customer API.

At first i tried to update the metafield using the customer API but it told me that the metafield already existed and i cannot add it again.

Then i used the user ID and made a call to retrieve all the metafields linked to the user using the metafield API - this worked and it returned all the metafields for me.

However my issue starts when i want to either delete or update the metafield that i've created.

I've tried a lot of different variations of REST calls but nothing seems to work.

To try and delete i used:

```
$baseUrl = "https://".$apikey.":".$password."@".$hostname."/admin/";
......
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl.'metafields/'.$metaID.'.json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

// Make the REST call, returning the result
$response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($response);
```

This did not do anything, so i tried going a level deeper and used the following URL:

```
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl.'customers/'.$custID.'/metafields/'.$metaID.'.json');
```

This URL did not work either.

Then I decided that i might as well just try and update the metafield to the new value that it was supposed to have.

I then tried the tried the following to update the value:

```
$metafield = array('metafields' => array(array(
                'id' => $metaID,
                'value' => '3',
                'value_type' => 'string',
              )));

$curl_url = $baseUrl.'customers/'.$custID.'/metafields/'.$metaID.'.json';

$ch = curl_init($curl_url);
$data_string = json_encode(array('metafield'=>$metafield));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($server_output);
```

After that i tried the alternative URL:

```
$curl_url = $baseUrl.'metafields/'.$metaID.'.json';
```

Any idea where i messed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 2 works now - creating and updating a metafield
So after writing and testing different sets of code i got something to work.

```
$data = array('metafield' => 
      array(
                'key' => 'level',
                'value' => '1',
                'value_type' => 'string',               
                'namespace' => 'Wholesaler'
            )
    );
    $curl_url = $baseUrl.'customers/'.$custID.'/metafields.json';
    //$ch = curl_init($baseUrl.$sid.'.json'); //set the url

$session = curl_init($curl_url);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-HTTP-Method-Override: POST') );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

if(ereg("^(https)",$curl_url)) curl_setopt($session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

$json = json_decode( $response, true );

var_dump($json);
echo "<br>-------------------------------------------------<br>";
echo $curl_url;
```

This code allowed me to create a metafield for a user that did not have it as well as update that metafield, as long as the key field and namespace makes it unique it will create a new field, if you use a key and namespace that already exists it will update the value.

I hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: You should merge your two answers (edit one and delete the other). There's no value in keeping them separated.

Answer (score 1):

I do this call and it works perfect everytime:

```
DELETE /admin/customers/123456789/metafields/987654321.json
```

Where my customer ID is 123456789 and the metafield I want to kill has the ID 987654321

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your response. Is the cURL options I'm using then wrong or am i missing something else?

Comment: I got my delete function working, now i just need to get the update/put function working as currently it is not giving me an error but it just dumps out the metafied as it was without it being updated.

Comment: Hello David, hey i'm using this path but with package from node. Almost works fine, but the pakage show me a messahe like ```API Deprecation Notice: {
  message: 'https://shopify.dev/changelog/online-store-2-0-new-metafields-type-system-and-dynamic-sources',
  path: 'https://promedtest.myshopify.com/admin/api/unstable/customers/5852137193636/metafields.json'
}```

Comment: Yes. My message was from 2015. You need to adjust to the reality in 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Part one is done  - Delete

After doing alot of research and trying different pieces of script the following worked for me:

```
$curl_url = $baseUrl.'customers/'.$custID.'/metafields/'.$metaID.'.json';
//$curl_url = $baseUrl.'metafields/'.$metaID.'.json';

    $session = curl_init($curl_url);

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

    if(ereg("^(https)",$curl_url)) curl_setopt($session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);

    $json = json_decode( $response, true );

    var_dump($json);
```

I can now delete a metafield.